# EMGU Gray TColor with UInt16 depth

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, emgucv

I have a 12 bit gray-scale camera and I want to use EMGU to process the image.

My problem is that I want to process the image at "UInt16"  TDepth and not the usual "Byte"

So initially I create an empty 2D image:

```
Image<Gray, UInt16> OnImage = new Image<Gray, UInt16>(960, 1280);
```

then I  create a for loop to transfer my Image from 1D vector form to a 2D image:

```
 for (int i=1; i< 960; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 1280; j++)
        {
            OnImage[i, j] = MyImageVector[Counter];
            Counter++;
        }
    }
```

where:

```
int[] MyImageVector = new int[1228800];
```

The problem is at the line :

```
OnImage[i, j] = MyImageVector[Counter];
```

where i get the following error message:

> Cannot Implicitly convert type "int" to "EMGU.CV.Structure.Gray"

Why this is happening?

Do you know any way that i can store Int values to an Emgu Image object???

Any alternative workaround would be also helpful.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not from the area of EMGU but it sounds like a pure C# question. Instead of using UInt16 you may define a class with a member of type UInt6. This class should inherit the Gray class. Be sure you are initializing the class correctly and updating the parent class on every change. Also be sure that the parent class is not updated directly but only through the child class.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I followed your instructions and it worked. I also found another solution which I will post here... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution to pass a 1D vector into a 2D EMGU.Image:

```
Image<Gray, Single> _myImage= new Image<Gray, Single>(Width, Height); 
Buffer.BlockCopy(MyVector, 0, _myImage.Data, 0, MyVector.Length * sizeof(Single));
```

This works much faster that 2 for loops...